# Setting up user models with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've recently come across `SQLAlchemy`, and as I had just been attempting to code something very similar to it, I think it's amazing. I've started on a new website, and I've just been working on some models to deal with users, which includes various bits such as remembering logins and resetting passwords.

Since I'm completely new to this, I'd appreciate if someone could take a glance and see if I'm using any bad practices that should not be done, or if any bits could be improved/made more efficient. I'd prefer to get it right from the start, instead of a year or two down the line when its too late to make any changes.

As to the layout of the models, I tried to group the physical columns together (so the order of the columns is correct if you need to open the database with something else), then set up a generic order that each model should follow to make things easier to deal with at a glance:

1. Columns (physical columns to edit)
2. Automatic (physical columns that are automatically edited by events)
3. Relationships
4. Other (things like hybrid_methods that act like columns)
5. Validators
6. Overrides (`__init__`, `__repr__`, etc)
7. Additional (methods that add functionality)

So a few things to note, retreiving the persistent login is actually done via a `classmethod`, where it'll search the database if you have a session open, and delete all sessions if the identifier check fails. I relied on the `validates` decorator to override setting values, doing things such as hashing the password. I also didn't use `backref` in relationships as it seems like it's better practice to give yourself more control over it.

```
import bcrypt
import time
import uuid
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import exc, validates


__all__ = ['db', 'User', 'Email', 'Activation', 'LoginAttempts', 'PasswordReset', 'PersistentLogin']


db = SQLAlchemy()


def unix_timestamp():
    return int(time.time())


def generate_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex


def password_hash(password, rounds=12):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=rounds))


def quick_hash(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = uuid.uuid4().hex
    return hashlib.sha256(str(x)).hexdigest()


class User(db.Model):
    """User accounts."""
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('email.row_id'), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.CHAR(60), nullable=False)
    activated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=0)
    permissions = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=0)

    # Automatic
    password_edited = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    email = db.relationship('Email')
    activation_codes = db.relationship('Activation', lazy=True)
    password_resets = db.relationship('PasswordReset', lazy=True)
    persistent_logins = db.relationship('PersistentLogin', lazy=True)

    # Other
    @hybrid_property
    def identifier(self):
        """Generate an identifier unique to the email and password."""
        return quick_hash(self.password + self.email.address)

    # Validation
    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, email):
        if not isinstance(email, Email):
            email = Email(email)
        return email

    @validates('password')
    def validate_password(self, key, password):
        return password_hash(password)

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, email, password, username=None):
        super(User, self).__init__(email=email, password=password, username=username)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{} ({})">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.username, self.email.address)


@db.event.listens_for(User, 'before_insert')
def user_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()
    target.updated = unix_timestamp()
    target.password_edited = unix_timestamp()


@db.event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def user_update(mapper, connection, target):
    target.updated = int(time.time())


@db.event.listens_for(User.password, 'set')
def user_password_update(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    """Update password edited time"""
    if value != oldvalue:
        target.password_edited = unix_timestamp()


class Email(db.Model):
    """Email addresses.
    More than one account can have the same email, but the intention is that it will have the
    permission of UserPermissions.Deleted.
    """
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # Automatic
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    users = db.relationship('User', lazy=True)
    login_attempts = db.relationship('LoginAttempts', lazy=True)

    # Validators
    @validates('address')
    def validate_address(self, key, address):
        assert '@' in address
        return address

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, address):
        super(Email, self).__init__(address=address)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.address)


@db.event.listens_for(Email, 'before_insert')
def email_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()
    target.updated = unix_timestamp()


@db.event.listens_for(Email, 'before_update')
def email_update(mapper, connection, target):
    target.updated = unix_timestamp()


class Activation(db.Model):
    """Activate user accounts.
    The (unhashed) code will be sent to the user via email, and visiting the URL within the
    allocated time will activate their account.
    If a new activation code is sent, then delete this record.
    """
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.row_id'), nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.CHAR(64), nullable=False, unique=True)

    # Automatic
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    user = db.relationship('User')

    # Validators
    @validates('user')
    def validate_email(self, key, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            user = User(user)
        return user

    @validates('code')
    def validate_code(self, key, code):
        return quick_hash(code)

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, user, token):
        super(PasswordReset, self).__init__(user=user, code=code)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.user.email.address)


@db.event.listens_for(Activation, 'before_insert')
def activation_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()


class LoginAttempts(db.Model):
    """Keep track of failed login attempts."""
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('email.row_id'), nullable=False)
    success = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=0)

    # Automatic
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    email = db.relationship('Email')

    # Validators
    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, email):
        if not isinstance(email, Email):
            email = Email(email)
        return email

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, email, success):
        super(PasswordReset, self).__init__(email=email, success=success)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.user.email.address)


@db.event.listens_for(LoginAttempts, 'before_insert')
def login_attempt_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()


class PasswordReset(db.Model):
    """Reset user account password.
    Make sure to delete this record as soon as its used.
    """
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.row_id'), nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.CHAR(64), nullable=False, unique=True)

    # Automatic
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    user = db.relationship('User')

    # Validators
    @validates('user')
    def validate_email(self, key, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            user = User(user)
        return user

    @validates('code')
    def validate_code(self, key, code):
        return quick_hash(code)

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, user, token):
        super(PasswordReset, self).__init__(user=user, code=code)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.user.email.address)


@db.event.listens_for(PasswordReset, 'before_insert')
def password_reset_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()


class PersistentLogin(db.Model):
    """Save logins between sessions.
    Information read from https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/2403000.

    Identifier:
        The same between all login sessions.
        1-64 = random hash, 65-128 = email hash
        When comparing the identifier, only force all the sessions to end if the email is correct.
        Otherwise someone could log everyone out by using the wrong session.
    Token:
        Unique for each session.
        This is just a basic check of whether it exists or not.
        If a match, generate a fresh token and overwrite.
    """
    # Columns
    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.row_id'), nullable=False)
    identifier = db.Column(db.CHAR(128), unique=True)
    token = db.Column(db.CHAR(64), unique=True)

    # Automatic
    created = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    user = db.relationship('User')

    # Validators
    @validates('user')
    def validate_email(self, key, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            user = User(user)
        return user

    @validates('token')
    def validate_token(self, key, token):
        return quick_hash(token)

    # Overrides
    def __init__(self, user, token):
        super(PersistentLogin, self).__init__(user=user, token=token)
        self.identifier = quick_hash() + user.identifier

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} "{}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.user.email.address)

    # Extra
    @classmethod
    def get_session(cls, user, token, identifier):
        """Use the token and identifier to get the current session.
        Returns the session model and the new token.
        """
        # Find record with matching token
        token = quick_hash(token)
        try:
            session = PersistentLogin.query.filter(PersistentLogin.token==token).one()
        except exc.NoResultFound:
            return None

        # Find if identifier is valid
        if session.identifier != identifier:
            if session.identifier[64:128] == session.user.identifier:
                all_sessions = PersistentLogin.query.filter(PersistentLogin.user.identifier==session.identifier)
                all_sessions.delete()
                db.session.commit()
            return None
        # Check the user identifier in case email/password has been changed
        elif session.identifier[64:128] != session.user.identifier:
            return None

        # Return the session with a new token
        return (session, session.regenerate_token())

    def regenerate_token(self):
        """Generate and set a new token."""
        token = generate_uuid()
        self.token = token
        return token


@db.event.listens_for(PersistentLogin, 'before_insert')
def persistent_login_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = unix_timestamp()
    target.updated = unix_timestamp()


@db.event.listens_for(PersistentLogin, 'before_update')
def persistent_login_update(mapper, connection, target):
    target.updated = int(time.time())
```

Here's my messy testing file, mainly to see if the persistent logins work

```
import os
import sys

from flask import Flask

# Import everything from the above file

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 123
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# Initialise the database and set the context (https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts)
db.init_app(app)
app.app_context().push()
db.create_all()

# Insert test user
admin = User(username='admin', email='admin@example.com', password='test')
db.session.add(admin)
db.session.commit()

# Setup persistent login for admin
token_gen = '35269gjgr942jg'
p = PersistentLogin(user=admin, token=token_gen)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()

# Read persistent login for admin
session, new_token = PersistentLogin.get_session(admin, token_gen, p.identifier)

# If password or email changes, then the persistent login should return None
admin.email = 'new@admin.com'
print PersistentLogin.get_session(admin, new_token, p.identifier)
```